# How can I email a terminal session typescript without raw data?

Tags: scripting, cat, typescript

I have a bash script that tries to kill two birds with one stone by running commands with `script -c` and writing the output to a log file so that I can monitor the progress, then email myself the results.

The final log file is quite long as it is a typescript of everything that was displayed in the terminal session; every single progress output is logged.
However, if I read the data with `cat`, I only get the final output showed in the terminal.

For instance:
`script -c 'rsync -ah --info=progress2 folder1 folder2' logfile.log`

Opening the file with `nano`:

```
> # nano logfile.log
Script started on 2021-07-20 14:22:40+0800
^M         36.84M   0%   34.31GB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=606/673)^M        808.26M   7%  752.75GB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#31, to-chk=603/673)^M        860.63M   7%  801.52GB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#34, to-chk=592/673)$

Script done on 2021-07-20 14:22:40+0800
```

Whereas, with `cat`

```
> # cat logfile.log                                                                                                                                                                                              
Script started on 2021-07-20 14:22:40+0800
         11.48G 100% 10693.06GB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#616, to-chk=0/673)

Script done on 2021-07-20 14:22:40+0800
```

However, if writing `cat` ouput to a file:

```
> # cat logfile.log > temp.log
```

The resulting `temp.log` will include the entire raw data.

---

1. What is the reason for the discrepencies?
2. I would like to email the same output as what I get from `cat` on display; not the raw output showed from `nano`.
   However, `cat` always output raw data whether to a file, another command, etc.

The command below emails raw data.

```
> # echo -e "Subject : report" "\n\n\n `cat logfile.log`" | sendmail hello@example.com
```

3. Is there any way to cleanup the typscript file from all the raw data afterwards? I didn't find anything online or in the manuals.

---

## Additional comment

Thanks for the suggestions & explanations.
Indeed I can cleanup the output from `rsync` with `tr` and `sed` as suggested in the comments.

However, if I run the command without `-v` or run a different program - for instance `restic` - the logs will show a lot erase sequences in the logs.

```
^[[2K[13:34] 487210 files 165.864 GiB, total 503917 files 230.290 GiB, 0 errors

^[[2K[13:34] 487218 files 165.972 GiB, total 503960 files 230.477 GiB, 0 errors

^[[2KFiles:         176 new,     3 changed, 633544 unmodified

^[[2K

^[[2KDirs:          260 new,   140 changed, 106144 unmodified

^[[2K

^[[2KAdded to the repo: 363.231 MiB

^[[2K

^[[2K

^[[2K

^[[2Kprocessed 633723 files, 535.105 GiB in 14:34

^[[2K

^[[2Ksnapshot 9394ca81 saved

^[[2K

^[[2K

^[[1A
Script done on 2021-07-20 00:06:12+0800
```

I can manage to delete those with `sed`.

It might cleaner and a more universal solution if there was a way to write the last output from the terminal as show by `cat` directly to a file or pipe it to `sponge` ?

Comment: `cat` outputs the raw data even to the terminal. It just does it so fast (pretty much as fast as the hardware allows), you can't see the intermediate states. It would be a different story if you had recorded the timing information with `script`'s `-T` option; you could then replay it with `scriptreplay`. Anyway, a crude way of cleaning it up is what you've done to post it: copying/pasting what you see in the terminal. I imagine you want something more automatic, though.

Comment: IIRC, `rsync` only uses a Carriage Return (aka CR,  Ctrl-M, ^M, or \r) to return to the start of the line in its progress displays.  Try `sed -e '/\r/d' logfile.log > temp.log` to delete the progress lines (and any other line containing a `\r`).  Alternatively, use `sed -e 's/\r.*//' ...` to remove everything after the first CR on a line (so you'd see the initial 0% display but not the 100% completed for each progress line).

Comment: Try `cat -v $FILE` to nullify the control codes, or `tr '\r' '\n' <$FILE` to just convert the CR to NL

Comment: @symcbean Wouldn't that still leave the unwanted extra text, though, just without some of the control codes that help erase it?

Comment: I added more information below the initial question

Comment: It doesn't seem trivial to do this automatically without duplicating some functions of a terminal emulator. You have to keep track of what the output looks like and change the appropriate characters when they get overwritten. Then you can output the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's a (relatively) simple Python script that attempts this cleanup. I call it `clean-typescript.py`. It can certainly be improved, and may contain bugs, but this is what I could come up with in a short time.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Takes raw terminal output of a program containing control sequences that
# overwrite parts of the output, and attempts to transform it to just the end
# result, writing its output on stdout.
#
# Assumptions/limitations:
#  * Assumes Unix line endings.
#  * Assumes input text is left-to-right, in system character encoding.
#  * Does not attempt to deal with most of the complexities of Unicode.
#  * Does not attempt to interpret every ANSI escape sequence; just the common
#    ones that affect cursor position.
#  * Ignores ANSI SGR (bold/color/etc.) sequences.
#  * Assumes 8-column tab stops.
#  * Assumes the terminal displays an unlimited number of lines.
#  * Ignores absolute positioning sequences (except CHA): this is not for
#    ncurses output and such.
#  * Will not allow the cursor to go up beyond the first line in the file.
#
# Usage: clean-typescript.py FILE COLS
# FILE is the name of the file to read; if omitted or "-", read stdin.
# COLS is how many columns wide the terminal is; if omitted, set to 80.

import sys
from array import array
from enum import Enum

if len(sys.argv) >= 2 and sys.argv[1] != "-":
    f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
else:
    f = sys.stdin

if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    cols = int(sys.argv[2])
else:
    cols = 80

lines = [array("u", (" ",)*cols)]
curline = curcol = 0
eol = False

class Dir (Enum):
    UP = 0
    DOWN = 1
    RIGHT = 2
    LEFT = 3

def move_cursor (dir: Dir, count: int):
    global curline, curcol, eol
    if dir == Dir.UP:
        pos = curline - count
        curline = pos if pos >= 0 else 0
    elif dir == Dir.DOWN:
        pos = curline + count
        curline = pos if pos < len(lines) else len(lines) - 1
    elif dir == Dir.RIGHT:
        pos = curcol + count
        curcol = pos if pos < cols else cols - 1
    elif dir == Dir.LEFT:
        eol = False
        pos = curcol - count
        curcol = pos if pos >= 0 else 0

def skip_osc ():
    c = f.read(1)
    while True:
        if c == "\x07":
            return f.read(1)
        if c == "\x1b":
            if f.read(1) == "\\":
                return f.read(1)
        c = f.read(1)

def interpret_seq ():
    c = f.read(1)
    if c == "]": # OSC
        return skip_osc()
    if c != "[": # CSI
        # Other Fe seqs. not supported
        return f.read(1)

    parms = []
    c = f.read(1)
    while True:
        p = ""
        while c >= "0" and c <= "9":
            p += c
            c = f.read(1)
        if p:
            parms.append(int(p))

        if c != ";": break
        c = f.read(1)

    if c == "A":   # CUU
        move_cursor(Dir.UP, parms[0] if len(parms) > 0 else 1)
    elif c == "B": # CUD
        move_cursor(Dir.DOWN, parms[0] if len(parms) > 0 else 1)
    elif c == "C": # CUF
        move_cursor(Dir.RIGHT, parms[0] if len(parms) > 0 else 1)
    elif c == "D": # CUB
        move_cursor(Dir.LEFT, parms[0] if len(parms) > 0 else 1)
    elif c == "E": # CNL
        move_cursor(Dir.LEFT, cols)
        move_cursor(Dir.DOWN, parms[0] if len(parms) > 0 else 1)
    elif c == "F": # CPL
        move_cursor(Dir.LEFT, cols)
        move_cursor(Dir.UP, parms[0] if len(parms) > 0 else 1)
    elif c == "G": # CHA
        move_cursor(Dir.LEFT, cols)
        move_cursor(Dir.RIGHT, parms[0] - 1 if len(parms) > 0 else 0)
    # CUP and ED not implemented
    elif c == "K": # EL
        if (len(parms) == 0 or parms[0] == 0) and not eol:
            for i in range(curcol, cols):
                lines[curline][i] = " "
        elif parms[0] == 1:
            for i in range(0, curcol):
                lines[curline][i] = " "
            if eol:
                append_line()
                move_cursor(Dir.LEFT, cols)
                move_cursor(Dir.DOWN, 1)
        elif parms[0] == 2:
            for i in range(0, cols):
                lines[curline][i] = " "
            if eol:
                append_line()
                move_cursor(Dir.LEFT, cols)
                move_cursor(Dir.DOWN, 1)
    # ED, SU, SD, and HVP also not implemented

    c = f.read(1)
    return c

def append_line ():
    lines.append(array("u", (" ",)*cols))

c = f.read(1)
while c:
    if c == "\x08":   # BS
        if eol:
            eol = False
        else:
            move_cursor(Dir.LEFT, 1)
    elif c == "\x09": # HT
        curcol = (curcol + 8)//8*8
        if curcol >= cols: curcol = cols - 1
    elif c == "\x0a": # LF (implies CR in Unix)
        eol = False
        if curline == len(lines) - 1: append_line()
        move_cursor(Dir.LEFT, cols)
        move_cursor(Dir.DOWN, 1)
    elif c == "\x0b" or c == "\x0c": # VT/FF: just go down one line
        if curline == len(lines) - 1: append_line()
        move_cursor(Dir.DOWN, 1)
    elif c == "\x0d": # CR (stays on same line)
        eol = False
        move_cursor(Dir.LEFT, cols)
    elif c == "\x1b": # Escape seq.
        c = interpret_seq()
        continue
    elif (c >= "\x20" and c <= "\x7e") or c >= "\xa1":
        if not eol: lines[curline][curcol] = c
        if curcol == cols - 1:
            if eol:
                if curline == len(lines) - 1: append_line()
                move_cursor(Dir.LEFT, cols)
                move_cursor(Dir.DOWN, 1)
                lines[curline][curcol] = c
                move_cursor(Dir.RIGHT, 1)
            else:
                eol = True
        else:
            move_cursor(Dir.RIGHT, 1)

    c = f.read(1)

# Final result
print(*("".join(line).rstrip() for line in lines), sep="\n", end="")
```